# Display validation message on button click for multiple tabs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have 7-8 `tabs` and each tab consist of `next` button. At the last tab there is `Submit` button.

> So, what I want is if user does not fill any fields in any of the tabs, A validation message should pop up saying that this field is not filled and the field should get highlighted.

I have written the validaton part in javascript like below

```
function SiteDetailsValidate() {
if ($("#ddlSiteType").val() == '--Select--' || $("#ddlSiteType").val() == null) {
    jAlert('Type of Site cannot be blank', 'INFORMATION');
    return false;
}
if ($('#txtSitePlotDimension').val() == "" || $('#txtSitePlotDimension').val() == null) {
    jAlert('Site/Plot Dimension cannot be blank', 'INFORMATION');
    return false;
}
if ($("#ddlTechnolgy").val() == '--Select--' || $("#ddlTechnolgy").val() == 0) {
    jAlert('Technology cannot be blank', 'INFORMATION');
    return false;
}
if ($("#ddlMountType").val() == '--Select--' || $("#ddlMountType").val() == 0) {
    jAlert('Mount Type cannot be blank', 'INFORMATION');
    return false;
}
if ($("#ddlAntennaSize").val() == '--Select--' || $("#ddlAntennaSize").val() == 0) {
    jAlert('Antenna size cannot be blank', 'INFORMATION');
    return false;
}
if ($('#txtAMSL').val() == "" || $('#txtAMSL').val() == null) {
    jAlert('AMSL cannot be blank', 'INFORMATION');
    return false;
}
if (!$("input[name='Platform']:checked").val()) {
    jAlert('Platform Required cannot be blank', 'INFORMATION');
    return false;
}
if ($('#txtPlatformHeight').val() == "" || $('#txtPlatformHeight').val() == null) {
    jAlert('Platform Height cannot be blank', 'INFORMATION');
    return false;
}
if (!$("input[name='Rooftype']:checked").val()) {
    jAlert('Rooftype Site cannot be blank', 'INFORMATION');
    return false;
}
if ($('#txtNoofFloorsBldg').val() == "" || $('#txtNoofFloorsBldg').val() == null) {
    jAlert('No Of Floors in Building cannot be blank', 'INFORMATION');
    return false;
}
if ($('#txtAddRoofTopSite').val() == "" || $('#txtAddRoofTopSite').val() == null) {
    jAlert('In addition to standard space requirement for Roof top Site additional space 5 Mtr * 4 Mtr for VSAT Antenna cannot be blank');
    return false;
}
if ($('#txtStructuralStability').val() == "" || $('#txtStructuralStability').val() == null) {
    jAlert('Structural Stability Certificate (SST) from Local Consultant cannot be blank', 'INFORMATION');
    return false;
}
if ($('#txtSatelliteBand').val() == "" || $('#txtSatelliteBand').val() == null) {
    jAlert('Satellite Band cannot be blank', 'INFORMATION');
    return false;
}
else {
    var abc = true;
    return abc;
}}
```

Here is my tab html and button click:-

```
<div class="tabList">
        <ul>
            <li class="tab first active"><a rel="#siteDetails" href="#">Site Details</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a rel="#antennaOrientation" href="#">Antenna Orientation</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a rel="#losclearance" href="#">LOS Clearance</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a rel="#cablesandelectrical" href="#">Cables &amp; Electrical</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a rel="#otherdetails" href="#">Other Details</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a rel="#panoramicPhotos" href="#">Panoramic Photos</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a rel="#satelliteLosSnaps" href="#">Satellite LOS Snaps</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a rel="#SitePlotLayout" href="#">Site /Plot Layout</a></li>
            <li class="tab last"><a rel="#SiteFinalizationReport" href="#">Site Finalization Report</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


<input class="formbutt submit" type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="return ValidateTSSRFields('Save');" />
```

Please suggest how should I will be able to fire the validation message on submit click and show on which tab it is giving alert.

Comment: you know which field is empty, based on that you can identify right?

Comment: First you move to that tab and then highlight the input

Comment: @MehulJoshi: yes, but I am bit confused on how to display for which tab the field is empty. Any idea on how to show that. IT would be great if u suggest

Comment: @Mr_Perfect: how ? any idea

Comment: Why can't you validate the inputs before moving to the next tab?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect: the requirement is not like that, that is why. Other wise I would have created functions to validate the inputs

Comment: Can you make plunker for this?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect: what is plunker? or are you talking about js fiddle ??

Comment: Both are similar. You can add anything

Comment: can you create fiddle?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect: sure just give me 2 mins., i will ping u the link

Comment: @Mr_Perfect: have a look https://jsfiddle.net/dkvoLpc4/

Comment: getting error. check the console

Comment: what is the error ? but I am not getting error at my end in console ..!

Comment: please update correctly

Comment: I am sorry, what I have left do let me know. As at my end i am not getting any error in console. is it related to min jquery ?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect: can you come on chat, I have found one way just need your help into implementing this.

Comment: @Mr_Perfect: please come here if possible. here i can explain you better https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148199/jquery-chat

Comment: @MehulJoshi: can u help me with this. if possible come on chat

Comment: please create fiddle for your code.